# Scenario steps in feature files are marked as having duplicate implementations

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

I am new to cucumber, i am facing some issue while using feature files.

My feature files are having step definitions  defined.But some times i am seeing an alert sign on cucumber feature files saying that there are duplicate step definitions defined .

1. tried updating the jar dependencies in pom.xml from info.cucks to 
   cucumber.io or versa
2. tried updating the versions

none of these are helpful.

Expected: 
1. My feature file should recognize the step definitions and stop showing alert "Multiple definitions found for 'steps' "

Screen shot of feature file with the warning
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the multiple step definitions for the steps.
For example:

```
Given block {
             line of code 1
             line of code 2
}  

//the same 
Given block {
             line of code 1
             line of code 2
             line of code 2
  }
```

In Cucumber, if you have a same step defined in feature file in different scenarios, then in step definition there should be only single step definition not multiple.

Comment: I do not have any such blocks in my feature file ,  i don't have any repeated steps too. I am adding screen shot of my feature file, please see it.

Comment: Try creating the feature file again by removing the previous one and check if it works, I don't see any issues there except if you had created such feature file in other project.

Comment: What i have realized is that , Other projects in my workspace , is having same steps, when i try to mouse hover the steps in feature file after click+hold ctrl button , i am given 2 options, 1 from that current project and another from previously created project. How should i solve this issue.

Comment: I would recommend, to make a copy of existing projects and delete from your work space and try again with your project. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: For the steps that give this warning, do you have multiple step definitions with the same tag/regex in your step definition files? (They don't have to be in the same file)